# Printer always homes X & Y at end of print

Tags: creality-cr-10, homing

I can't figure out why, but at the end of every print, my Creality CR-10 Smart Pro will move the print head left until it hits the limit switch and move the bed back until it hits its limit switch. I have no idea why.

I have looked at the G-code of several prints and I don't see any command telling the printer to do this. I have also tried different slicers and the same thing happens. I have tried adding `M18` to disable the steppers at the end of the G-code hoping it wouldn't do this if the steppers were off, but no luck. I can only assume that this behavior is built into the printer for some odd reason.

Can anyone else with a Creality CR-10 Smart Pro confirm that their printer also does this?

Comment: If anyone wants to see the last 20 lines of my most recent print. I don't see anything that would cause my printer to move to its limit switches.
`G1 X149.707 Y150.217 E0.74249
;;retract;;
G1 F1200 E0.46249
G1 F3600 X150 Y150.199
G1 X149.707 Y150.217 E0.44579
G1 F1200 E0.34249
G0 F7200 X150 Y149.545
;TYPE:WALL-OUTER
G1 F2400 E0.74249
G1 F600 X150 Y149.233 E0.74984
;TIME_ELAPSED:14.258935

G1 F1200 E0.34984
M140 S0
G1 F600 Z0.78
G0 F7200 X250 Y280 Z0.78
M106 P2 S0
G91 ;Relative positionning
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
M104 S0
;End of Gcode`

Comment: If you believe that the last 20 lines are relevant, please [edit] your question to add in the info. Comments can/will be deleted over time.